# How can I scrape information from HowLongToBeat.com? It doesn't use a variable in the URL

Tags: python, scrape

I'm trying to scrape information from [How Long to Beat](http://www.howlongtobeat.com/), how can I make a request for a search without having to put the search-term in the URL?

EDIT for clarity:

The problem I face is that the site **doesn't** use something like http://www.howlongtobeat.com/search.php?s=**search-term**, therefore I cannot do something like

```
url         = 'http://www.howlongtobeat.com/search.php?s='
search_term = raw_input("Search: ")

r = requests.get(url + search_term)
```

In other words, when you type the search-term in the search dialog, the site doesn't refresh nor show a change in the URL so I can't find a way to search from outside the site.

I'm sorry if I made grammar mistakes, english is not my first language.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the site, but notice that the URLs for the game pages follow a pattern, e.g. `http://www.howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=1` through `id=19698`. If you're just looking for the game data (i.e. not the users), you could probably take advantage of the predictable URLs and crawl the detail pages by iterating through the range of id's.

Comment: what are you trying to scrape? which pages? may be you can find a pattern and make use of it?

Comment: I will edit for clarity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the page is driven by [AJAX requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) - it updates automatically without redirecting you to visible URL.

If you open developer tools in your browser (F12) and navigate to Network panel, you will see that there are indeed requests sent to the server. I typed "test2" and got following:

[image: Screenshot from Developer Tools in Firefox]

As you see, request is sent to a URL that looks like this: `http://www.howlongtobeat.com/search_main.php?t=games&page=1&sorthead=popular&sortd=Normal%20Order&plat=&detail=0`.
I typed "test2", but it's nowhere to be seen.

That's because it was sent using [POST request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29), e.g. the parameters were embedded in the HTTP request itself, not the URL. When I navigated to "Params" tab in the Developer Tools, indeed I could see my input:

> queryString: "test2"

So in order to use this search form, you should send a POST request to that URL containing variable "queryString" filled with whatever value you need.

I strongly encourage asking the site owners' about an API, though. Using publicly available form engines that are designed to be used by end-users in automated fashion is considered unethical.

Comment: I didn't know it was considered unethical (may I ask why?), I will ask in the forums about an API.

Comment: I think that's material for a different question. [Here is an example of such question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/24804/is-page-scraping-and-data-mining-moral-legal) on Programmers SE.